# What is the best way to store a list of small instructions?

Tags: c++, data-structures, vala

I want to do a small artificial life simulator in C++ or Vala. I can't decide how to write a gene class. A gene consists of a set of assembler-like instructions that are stored in a very small class, like:

```
rnd 0 10
add .0 20
mov .0 $accel
```

First, should I use linked list of array (std::list or std::vector)?

Second, should I encapsulate the array into the class or leave it public? If I choose the former, I will have to wrap many of the functions of the list. The latter violates encapsulation.

Comment: have you considered using a database?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Almost surely a `vector`; a `list` would give you only overhead (in terms of memory used and time spent navigating the list), giving you no advantage (I don't think your genes need to have code continuously inserted in the middle, and even so if the data is small the `vector` still wins).
2. If the clients of the class need to manipulate almost freely the list of instructions anyway I see no use in encapsulating it and then adding tons of small wrapper functions.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the exact number or maximum (that isn't much greater than expected) number of elements then you are best of using a `std::array<T>` (has one too if your not down with C++11 yet).

The the number of elements is not know then use a `std::vector<T>`.

If the number of elements is likely to change frequently then use a `std::deque<T>`

if you want a container of sets of instructions then you have to make more predictions.

you might end up with

```
std::deque<std::array<T, 4> > life_forms;
```

that particular case would be good if you expected to be adding life forms frequently and every life form had exactly 4 instructions.

Note I would highly discourage using a list unless you want to 'remove' links frequently.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a [small genetic programming framework](https://gitorious.org/pigp/libmlgp) in vala. I've just used simple arrays of structs (op, p1, p2) to represent the instructions.